# My very basic code using input, map and int geves me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

I used this code in google collab to ask user for input date
but on execution of the code I get

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
from datetime import datetime

date_entry = input('Enter a date (i.e. 2017,7,1)')  
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split(','))
date = datetime(year, month, day)
```

I am not calling any string, what is wrong?

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, it doesn't trigger any error

Comment: You probably assigned `input` or `map` somewhere to a string. Check your previous lines and avoid using Python built-ins as variable names  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html.

Answer (score 0):

Python has several function (`int`, `input`, `map`, `list`, `set`, `dict`, `min`, `max`, ...) as [build ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) that you use in your code.

Those functions have names that are not protected from being used otherwise. Using them as variable names however hides the *original* function from being accessed.

Doing so leads to this kind of error message.

Demo:

```
from datetime import datetime

# store the original functions under different name for restoring them later
old_int = int
old_map = map
old_input = input
old_dt = datetime

for what in ["int", "map", "input", "datetime"]:
    # restore original functions to their names
    int, map, input, datetime = old_int, old_map, old_input, old_dt

    # set current function to be a string
    if what == "int": 
        int = "some string"
    elif what == "map": 
        map = "some string"
    elif what == "input": 
        input = "some string"
    else: 
        datetime = "some string"

    print(f"The '{what}' function was overwritten to be a string")

    # try to use the overwritten function and print the error message if it happens
    try:
        date_entry = input('Enter date: ')
        year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split(','))
        date = datetime(year, month, day)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, "\n")
```

Output:

```
The 'int' function was overwritten to be a string
Enter date: 2021,2,2
'str' object is not callable 

The 'map' function was overwritten to be a string
Enter date: 2021,2,2
'str' object is not callable 

The 'input' function was overwritten to be a string
'str' object is not callable 

The 'datetime' function was overwritten to be a string
Enter date: 2021,2,2
'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score -1):

The code is correct. it's the issue of indentation.
[image: attached image]

Comment: I think the indentation is just incorrect copy-paste. Incorrect indentation will not result in a "*TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*" as the OP mentioned.